# Laravel Accessing variable of other function

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.4, one-time-password

I have a `sendOtp()` method using which i have to send `otp` to the user for changing password in `changePassword()` method

i want to return the `$otp` from the `sendOtp()` to `changePassword()`

The `sendOtp` method

```
public function sendOtp($user_phone_number)
{
    $otp = mt_rand(100000, 999999); 

    //sms login

    $data = [
        'data' => [
            'otp' => $otp
        ]
    ];

    return Response::json(
        $data_with_status = array_merge($this->respondSuccess('otp sent'), $data)
    );
}
```

The `changePassword()` method

```
public function changePasswordOtp($user_phone_number)
{
    $user = User::where('phone_number', '=', $user_phone_number)->count();

    if($user > 0) {

        $this->sendOtp($user_phone_number); 

        //return response with sent otp
    }
    else {

        return Response::json(
            $this->respondFailure('User not found')
        );

    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @pinoyCoder thank you for your time, i'm not getting any response from the `sendOtp()` method, but the method is executing

Comment: @pinoyCode  i want to access the `$otp` from `sendOtp()` and return it in the `changePAssword()` method to the user(api for app) to match the `otp`

Comment: That is strange, check the developer console of you web browser, are you using ajax to send the request ?

Comment: Where are you receiving the response returned from `sendOtp` method?

Comment: @B. Desai  that's what i'm looking for, how to receive response from `sendOtp()` all i need is `$otp` sent to the user, thank you

Comment: `$result_otp = $this->sendOtp($user_phone_number); echo $result_otp;die;` and see what is printing

Comment: @B. Desai  it will work if i `echo` it but i want to send it in `json` format for `mobile application` i'm getting all these headers `HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Thu, 29 Jun 2017 07:37:14 GMT
{"status_code":200,"status_message":"otp sent","data":{"otp":373441}}`

Comment: @MrRobot see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive `otp` by following code:

```
public function changePasswordOtp($user_phone_number)
{
    $user = User::where('phone_number', '=', $user_phone_number)->count();

    if($user > 0) {

        $result_otp = $this->sendOtp($user_phone_number); 
         $result_otp = json_decode($result_otp ,true);

        $otp = $result_otp['data']['otp']; //return response with sent otp
    }
    else {

        return Response::json(
            $this->respondFailure('User not found')
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time it works if i just `return $this->sendOtp($user_phone_number); `

Answer (score 0):

Change your `sendOtp` like this :

```
public function sendOtp($user_phone_number)
{
    $otp = mt_rand(100000, 999999); 

    //sms login

    $data = [
        'data' => [
            'otp' => $otp
        ]
    ];
    $responseMessage= $this->respondSuccess();
    $responseArray = array_merge(responseMessage, data);
    return Response::json($responseArray); 
    );
}
```